# How to create button in the message that is sent in the email?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, html-email

I have developed feature in my application where users can request password recovery. All they need to do is enter the email address. System will provide the message like this:

`An email has been sent to example@gmail.com with further instructions.`

Then on the back end I check first if email exists in the system. If does exists I sent an email to the user that looks like this:

```
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;">
    <br>We recieved a password reset request. The link to reset your password is below.<br>
    <br>If you did not make this request, you can ignore this email.<br>
    <br>Here is your password reset link: <a href="https://example.com/index.cfm?token=12453244">Click here</a> as soon as possible and change your password.<br>
</div>
```

In the email above I would like to create the button that will be an option for the user to `In Activate` the link if they did not make the request for password change. I'm wondering how and what is the best way to implement that feature in the email?

Comment: What is the `In Activate` option? Also, why does it need to be a button, instead of a link - remember that not all people view email in HTML capable clients.

Comment: @vlaz I have explained why, if user did not make request for password recovery (it was accidentally submitted by someone else) we shoudl give them an option do in activate that link. That means that link won't be valid any more. Also, this html is just example of how I created the email content. User will see the text only not HTML code.

Comment: So `In Activate` should actually be `deactivate`, is that correct? Other than that, why not just expire the link automatically in an hour or a day or something? I've never seen a web application that lets you manually expire password recovery links - they are just not usable after a while.

Comment: @vlaz I do have set expiration date/time for the link. The link will expire after 30min. This is more like an extra security option. Why keep the link valid for another 30min if user dis not make that request.  In that case they probably can click on Deactivate and link will expire. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Most sites I've visited have that option on the target page itself, rather than as a direct link in the email itself. But, what's to stop you from creating another link - that when clicked does whatever inactivation code you need - as @vlaz suggested? How you choose to "style" the link (appear as link, button, etc..) with CSS is up to you...

Comment: If someone requests a reset for the wrong account, what is the impact if it just expires naturally? Since this isn't something that will likely be used on a regular basis, you may be just as well off letting it expire. Or just use another link to a page that does nothing but log and remove the request. Regardless, you've got a 30 minute window for the wrong person to request a reset and then the affected user to get the email notification and then click to deactivate the link. This may just not be worth the additional effort, other than maybe the logging to identify abuse.

Answer (score 3):

You can style your tag with inline css and make it look like a button.

```
<a href='site.com/passwordRecovery' style='padding:1em; background-color:blue;color:white;display:block'>Click Me</a>
```

Keep in mind that most email providers like google or hotmail disable using JavaScript or external css.

Comment: Your codes missing display block to make it into a block element. Email clients are notorious when it comes to rendering html code. Maybe give the code for the bullet proof button from email on acid?